# Mosquito bites as Poisson process

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-process

> Let number of mosquitos landing on a victim be a Poisson process with
>   intensity $\lambda$. Each mosquito bites victim with probability $p$
>   independently of others. Prove that total number of bites is a Poisson
>   process with intensity $p \lambda$.

Let $X_t$ be a total number of bites until the moment $t$. To be a Poisson process it should satisfy

1. $X_0 = 0$
2. if $t<s\leq u<r$ then $X_r-X_u$ and $X_s-X_t$ are independent
3. for $t\geq s$ $X_t-X_s$ is Poisson distributed

1 is obvious but 2 and 3 aren't clear for me. Since the Poisson distribution with intensity $\lambda$ is $\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}$ then probability that total number of mosquitoes will be $k$ at the moment $t$ is given by $P(X_t=k) = \int\limits_0^t \frac{(\lambda x)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda x}dx$.

Am I right? If yes, how to evaluate such integral without computer algebra systems? Then, define the result of integration by $I(t)$ I woild like to say that total number of bites until the moment $t$ is $\int\limits_0^t p^{I(x)} dx$, since at every moment $t_0$ there are $I(t_0)$ mosquitoes, each biting independently with probability $p$.

I would be very glad if anyone explain me how it should be proved.

Comment: One usually rather uses identities such as $$X_t=\sum_{k=1}^{N_t}B_k$$ with what I hope are obvious notations. Can you proceed?

Comment: @Did, I understand the meaning of this representation and all notations are clear ($N_t$ is the total number of mosquitoes at $t$, $B_k$ is a number of bites done by a single mosquito till moment $k$), but have troubles with finding $N_t$ and $B_k$. As for $B_k$ I think that it is just $p\cdot k$ and $N_t = \int\limits_0^t \lambda dx$, since the path of Poisson process has a leap on a $dt$ interval with probability $\lambda dt$. Is it true?

Comment: Sorry but you are confusing random variables (such as $N_t$ and the $B_k$s) with numbers... How so?

Comment: @Did, I thought about it and have some new ideas, may you check it? Denote by $N$ and $K$ number of bites and by $M$ number of mosquitoes, then $P(N=k) = \sum\limits_{m,k} P(M=m, K=k) = \sum\limits_{m\geq n} P(K=k \vert M=m)\cdot P(M=m)$. Here $P(K=k \vert M=m) = p^m(1-p)^{m-k}\binom{m}k$ is a binomial distribution and $P(M=m)=\frac{e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda t)^m}{m!}$ is a Poisson distribution. Is it true?

Comment: With $N=K$? Yes this approach will allow you to prove that the number $N_t$ of bites until time $t$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $p\lambda t$. But you are asked about the process $(N_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ itself...